# USRP X310 with host-PC time latency

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am working on a power line (PLC) channel emulator and I am using USRP X310 as the hardware platform and GNU Radio the software for the PLC- emulator. 
I would like to ask if it is possible to perform a real time channel emulator with SDR- platform and how can i perform the time without collision.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I've done that last week in my lab.

Just use the timed commands facility of the USRP to give you a determined RX/TX delay, and implement your channel model on your PC.

Comment: thank you @Marcus for your answer ... I'm using now the Labview program and before designing my system I wanna know how to check the time required to transfer the data from the USRP to PC and How long it will take to process the packet of data and transmitted again?

Comment: That's something no-one can tell you – it depends on so many factors, including your PC, your OS, your PC's workload, what Labview does.... by the way, I'm not even sure labview supports timed commands, so I can't tell you whether you can implement something like this in labview

Comment: what is the best option to do it ? and if i will use PCIe cable do you think it will work?

Comment: The PCIe interface has, to my experience, little latency advantage over 10Gig Ethernet, but it's the recommended connectivity for X3x0 + Labview, for some Labview reason. I really don't know labview, though, so I can't help you much with that.